# Cannot Deploy Charms from Charm Store

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

Ran into a strange problem, on `juju 1.24.2-utopic-amd64` and `1.7.0+bzr3299-0ubuntu1~utopic`, when trying to deploy a charm to a node, e.g.

```
juju deploy --config ./kilo.yaml nova-compute nova-compute-01 --to 25 --debug
```

Juju attempts to upload the charm from local repository! Looking into the `/var/log/juju/unit-nova-compute-01.log` of the target machine I see the following:

```
...
2015-08-18 22:51:24 INFO juju.worker.uniter.charm bundles.go:60 SSL hostname verification disabled
2015-08-18 22:51:24 INFO juju.utils http.go:59 hostname SSL verification enabled
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:507 charm check skipped, not yet installed.
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:325 got service change
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:507 charm check skipped, not yet installed.
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:341 got relations change
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:317 got unit change
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:398 ModeInstalling cs:trusty/nova-compute-26 exiting
2015-08-18 22:51:24 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:144 unit "nova-compute-gpu01/0" shutting down: ModeInstalling cs:trusty/nova-compute-26: failed to download charm "cs:trusty/nova-compute-26" from "http://10.4.0.17/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=cb285162-43c4-11e5-9f2f-080027fc4200&op=get_by_key": cannot download "http://10.4.0.17/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=cb285162-43c4-11e5-9f2f-080027fc4200&op=get_by_key": bad http response: 404 NOT FOUND
2015-08-18 22:51:24 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:116 tomb: dying
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter runlistener.go:97 juju-run listener stopping
2015-08-18 22:51:24 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter runlistener.go:117 juju-run listener stopped
2015-08-18 22:51:24 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:218 exited "uniter": ModeInstalling cs:trusty/nova-compute-26: failed to download charm "cs:trusty/nova-compute-26" from "http://10.4.0.17/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=cb285162-43c4-11e5-9f2f-080027fc4200&op=get_by_key": cannot download "http://10.4.0.17/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=cb285162-43c4-11e5-9f2f-080027fc4200&op=get_by_key": bad http response: 404 NOT FOUND
2015-08-18 22:51:24 INFO juju.worker runner.go:252 restarting "uniter" in 3s
2015-08-18 22:51:27 INFO juju.worker runner.go:260 start "uniter"
2015-08-18 22:51:27 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:217 starting juju-run listener on unix:/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-nova-compute-gpu01-0/run.socket
2015-08-18 22:51:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:115 unit "nova-compute-gpu01/0" started
2015-08-18 22:51:27 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter runlistener.go:84 juju-run listener running
2015-08-18 22:51:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:396 ModeContinue starting
2015-08-18 22:51:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:31 loading uniter state
2015-08-18 22:51:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:34 charm is not deployed
2015-08-18 22:51:27 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:757 new environment change
2015-08-18 22:51:27 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:398 ModeContinue exiting
2015-08-18 22:51:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:396 ModeInstalling cs:trusty/nova-compute-26 starting
2015-08-18 22:51:27 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:277 fetching charm "cs:trusty/nova-compute-26"
...
```

Note that http://10.4.0.17/ is my MAAS server. Similar thing happens when I attempt to use Juju's web gui.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the error clear :  failed to download charm "cs:trusty/nova-compute-26" from "http://10.4.0.17/MAAS/api/1.0/files/": cannot download "http://10.4.0.17/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=cb285162-43c4-11e5-9f2f-080027fc4200&op=get_by_key": bad http response: 404 NOT FOUND